# SSIS Job Error : ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection

Tags: mysql, ssis, ado.net, sql-server-agent

SQL server agent Job Error : ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection - with the following error message: "Could not create a managed connection manager.".

Hi Guys,

I have create a ssis package where the source is mysql ( Ado net source) and destination is OLEDB ( sql server) , data accessing remotely, I can run the package successfully without any errors, I have deployed them succesfully to another sql server , when i am creating a job schedule for this package and i am getting the above error , Please help if you have any idea how to resolve it .

NOTE : In SSIS package to check the ado net source connection when i am testing the connection it throws me an error saying test connection failed but when i close it and run the package it is successfully running.

Comment: Do you have access to both sql and mysql server from server where you deployed your SSIS package?

Comment: it might run successfully because of offline connection. Find a way to resolve your source connection error.

Comment: Hi Dragan, Yeah my network team installed mysql in the deployed server and given the credentials they can connect to it succesfully